# Getting the Les Paul Google Logo To Work Outside Google

Tags: flash

I've been trying to get the Les Paul Google Logo to work in my server the entire day. I almost got everything working, except the sound, but why I can't get the sound to work? What I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code I'm using: https://github.com/nathanpc/lespaul-google-logo.

Comment: I'm not sure how many people will be willing to download a file. JSFiddle?

Comment: Made a GitHub for it so everyone can fork and commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it uses Flash for the sound.  Maybe you have it blocked in your browser config?

Comment: I don't get anything on my debug console using Safari... It worked on your browser?

Comment: Yes, the version served from Google is working for me on FF 4.0.1/Win XP, also with Safari 5/OS X 10.5.8.